# Using comma/space in variable output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, navicat

I'm trying to output a SELECT with comma or even space but I can't design the database structure to use commas och space.

Database:

Cash Varchar 255 Decimals 0 and Default 50000 (I want it to be 50 000 or 50,000)

PHP:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$get = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '.$id.'')
<?php echo $get_row['cash']; ?>
```

Comment: Your description of 'Database:' makes zero sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to change the `cash` field to `decimal(10,2)` and use [number_format](https://www.php.net/number_format) instead of using `varchar` it's not right format for money/currency value.

```
//  You want spaces instead of comma and dot
number_format($value, 2, ' ', ' '); // 100000.00 becomes 100 000 00
```

Comment: I want to use spaces not commas and dots.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do that in your database. That's where you should just store the number (unformatted). Formatting is for the **display** script: UI, view, HTML, output etc.

In PHP, do something like this:

```
$value_from_database = 50000; // use $get_row['cash']
// output in view:
echo '$' . number_format($value_from_database, 2, ',', '.'); // $50,000.00 etc
echo number_format($value_from_database, 0, '', ' '); // 50 000 etc
```

**Manual:** http://php.net/number_format

Comment: The thing is the cash is going to be changing all the time, I just want it to be like 50 000, and when it changes it goes like 54 329 or even 2345.

1
10
100
1000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000
1 000 000 000, How do i output it with space?

Comment: Yep, you store the unformatted numbers in the database and add the spaces, commas etc when you want to display it.